# How can I implement separate but similar spring messages.properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a project that lets users apply for a credit card, which is basically a clone of a previous project(not made by me) but with different text, pictures, etc...

I want to reuse as much of the code as possible from the previous project, but I am not very familiar with spring and how to manipulate it. I have made two versions of the messages.properties file, one with the original text and one with the new text. How can I get the project to use one file or the other, perhaps based on a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way you can do it is like this :

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/my.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

Then you can add some if statements if you want the application to use different files.

Answer (score 0):

It it is a webapp.
Read about `org.springframework.context.MessageSource`. You can implement your own `MessageSources` and return the text you want to, depends on any conditions.